# How to make automatically line break when use longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I use `longtable` package to produce a table covers two pages, but if there are too many words in one column, the sentence can not switch to the next line automatically, see picture, the 4th column.[image]
Below is the "code"

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth    entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4dddddddddddd asdfdasfasdf asödflkjasdf asdfasdfasdf \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1   & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I change

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
```

to

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|p{6cm}|}
```

The fourth column can swith line, but the lines of columns have problem, see below
[image]
How to produce the table correctly?

Comment: This is exacty the same as `tabular` and `array` and any other latex alignment `{|c|c|c|c|}` specifies one-line cells if you need fixed width cells with line breaking use `p{3cm}` instead of `c`

Comment: If I change the 4th `c` to `p{6cm}` in your example I do _not_ see the image you get: the table all lines up (but it is `39.68738pt too wide` as reported in the log)

Comment: When you change something in a longtable you should compile at least twice so that the widths can be recalculated correctly.

Comment: After i consecutively run it several times, it shows okei after the second time, all lines up. I just remember someone said for longtable package, "table will not line up correctly until this document has been run through LATEX several times." Is it true? This is terrible! Users must check the result and wait several times to get the correct result when they print PDF??

Comment: Yes. And users must also wait several times to get correct references, tableofcontents, citations, tikz overlays and other things. Get used to it. A correct document needs a number of compilation until everything is in place.

Answer (score 13):

You need `p{5cm}` the same as in `tabular` to specify a cell that works like `\parbox`.
6cm and the default inter-column space made a table wider than the page, so I reduced both. Also don't put `longtable` in a `center` environment.

If you edit a longtable (including changing `c` to `p`) it can take a few runs for all parts of the table to line up, which may account for your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|p{5cm}|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth    entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4dddddddddddd asdfdasfasdf asödflkjasdf asdfasdfasdf \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1   & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: postit obviously didn't compile twice and so the wrong width from the previous run got him/her wrong lines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I wrote that originally then I persuaded myself that it wouldn't have looked quite like that but I think you're right, I'll edit.

Comment: Yes, my problem is i didnot compile it several times. If all users must compile twice to get a PDF file, i doubt if our customer still want to buy our software... No better solutions?

Comment: @postit latex almost always needs multiple runs to resolve cross references etc, if your software is calling it as a black box to generate pdf just make it run latex again if the log file says rerun latex

Comment: "Also don't put longtable in a center environment." Why not?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah it can not do anything at all useful, it does not center it, it just adds spurious vertical space when `\LTpre` and `\LTpost` are already adding space.

Comment: You're right! I tested and longtables are already automatically centered.