# longtable: Prevent page break after specific rows

Tags: longtable

- I strongly assume that I miss the obvious.
- **I have a [`longtable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and want to prevent a page break after specific rows.**
- After looking at the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and looking at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344270), I assumed that `\\*` or `\nopagebreak` will do the job.
- However, somehow I do not get the following MWE to work as expected: **Some Header C** should not be "alone" at the end of a page.
- What am I missing?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% "margin = 52mm" is used to control the page break for the MWE.
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 52mm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.40\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}}
% Inspired by % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194150
% --- First Head ---
\caption{Caption.}\\\toprule
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}\\\toprule
\endfirsthead
% --- Other Head ---
\caption*{\textit{Continued from previous page.}}\\\toprule
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}\\\toprule
\endhead
% --- Other Foots ---
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page.}} \\
\endfoot
% --- Last Foot ---
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% --- Actual Contents ---
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Some Header A}}\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Some Header B}}\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Some Header C (Should not be before a page break.)}}\\*\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Some Header D}}\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\end{longtable}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Screenshot from the actual table:*

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186702/2388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
% "margin = 54mm" is used to control the page break for the MWE.
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 54mm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Caption},
]{
  colspec = {t{0.25\linewidth}t{0.40\linewidth}t{0.25\linewidth}},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule
  A & B & C \\
\toprule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\SetCell[c=3]{l}\textbf{Some Header A} & & \\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\SetCell[c=3]{l}\textbf{Some Header B} & & \\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\SetCell[c=3]{l}\textbf{Some Header C (Should not be before a page break.)} & & \\*\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
\SetCell[c=3]{l}\textbf{Some Header D} & & \\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and also for the package!